# mysqlite table already in database must create via code

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, sqliteopenhelper

I created a table (Results) on SqliteBrowser, 1st the code complaints that the table does not exist.  It works if insert the following code:

```
 db.execSQL("create table Results (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Question text not null, Rights text not null, Wrongs text not null);");
```

but when I check the data with the following code the database, data is not there:

```
 public void checkTable(String table)  {
          String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + table + "" ;
    Cursor d = myDataBase.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
    while (d.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("CheckTable Content:", "" + table + ":Fields:" + d.getString(1) + " " + d.getString(2) + " " + d.getString(3));

    }
}
```

Why do can't code recognized the table already created via sqlitebrowser, why do I have create the table again? and why I can't see my data from the table if the insertorthrow worked fine?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you write the function to create the database, but check how i do it:
first create the java to create the table(s) in a string

```
String sqlCreate   = "CREATE TABLE Tutores       (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nombre_tutor TEXT)";
String sqlCreate2  = "CREATE TABLE Tutorados     (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nombre_tutorado TEXT, id_tutor REFERENCES Tutores(_id))";

public AgendaSqlite(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);

}
```

run the sql sentence to create it in the same java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     //Se ejecuta la sentencia SQL de creacion de la tabla
    db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    db.execSQL(sqlCreate2);
}

@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}
```

update the table

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //eliminamos la version anterior de la tabla
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tutores"); 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tutorados"); 

    //aqui creamos la nueva version de la tabla
    db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    db.execSQL(sqlCreate2);

}
```

then, in the main activity connect to the AgendaSqlite or whatever you called it, and put this code:

```
AgendaSqlite usdbh = new AgendaSqlite(this, ArchivoDB, null, 1);        
        SQLiteDatabase db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();
```

next, in a button you can check if you have something in the db with

```
if(db != null)
                {
                        //do something select, insert, etc

                }
```

hope that helps, see ya

Comment: Why i have to create the table when I had already created the tables in mysqlite browser?

Comment: well, like you said: "why do I have create the table again?" i rather do it with a java class than other way, so, i suggest you to do it that way, but it depends on you